# “Ok-Key” and “Cancel-Key”, Which One Should Be Set Up on the Left?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, web-app, design-patterns

“Ok-key” and “cancel-key”, [which one should be set up on the left](https://www.mockplus.com/blog/post/okkey-and-cancelkey-which-one-should-be-set-up-on-the-left?r=cherry-zjj)? It’s an eternal war of button sort between UI designers preferring “ok/cancel” type and the adherents of “cancel/ok” type, both sticking to their own viewpoints and not reaching a consensus.[image]So, what's your viewpoint?

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704951/order-of-ok-apply-cancel-buttons

Answer (score 1):

If Ok is placed on the left - They’ll first see the primary action on the left and then look at the secondary action on the right. Then they’ll move their eyes back to the primary action to click it. This creates a total of three visual fixations in multiple directions.

Whereas if the Ok button is placed is placed on right there will be only two visual fixations.

For Reference: http://uxmovement.com/buttons/why-ok-buttons-in-dialog-boxes-work-best-on-the-right/

**Primary button is usually placed on the right and secondary button the left.**

Comment: I have a question, maybe it's not professional. Shall we consider the operation habit of users? People always play or operate by right hands, does the OK key should be set on right?

Answer (score 0):

The default answer is: which ever is consistent with the rest of your app.

If you want to know what should be proper -- buttons that are progressive (OK, Save, Next, etc) should be on the far right much like when you turn the page of a book. Any regressive button (Cancel, No, Reset, etc) should be on the left much like going backwards IF you live in a Western world (read left to right).

This is a lot like the Back and Forward buttons. Back is always on the left while Forward is always on the right.

Comment: So, to a certain extent, it depends on where the APP or website used?

Answer (score 0):

You follow the human interface guidelines (or convention) for your platform.

For example, on Windows, an OK button (or equivalent) should be on the left, whereas a Cancel button should be on the right.